# HTML5 Drag and Drop - keep original effect with offset

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am setting a drag and drop on my project, and I want to keep the original drag effect, but just offset it a bit down. Is there a way to do that?

I was thinking to use `setDragImage()` - but this requires that I generate an image. Is there a way to keep the original effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While PLaying around I discovered that I can use this to keep the iamge

```
setDragImage(this,0,0)
```